# Readonly richtextbox changing color of keyword C#

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, richtextbox

I have a rich text box that i am using to display an example of the Hello World program and want the keywords such as 'using' 'namespace' 'class' 'static' 'void' 'string' to display blue.

I have got 'using' to display blue but only when the user starts to type or types 'using' 
I want the richtextbox to be read only not allowing an user input into it

Here is my code:

```
    private void rtb_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string find = "using";
        if (rtb.Text.Contains(find))
        {
            var matchString = Regex.Escape(find);
            foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(rtb.Text, matchString))
            {
                rtb.Select(match.Index, find.Length);
                rtb.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                rtb.Select(rtb.TextLength, 0);
                rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor;
            };
        }
    }
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to do it for readonly rtb. 
How could i edit my code to display the blue text on initialize in a readonly rtb

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to subscribe to the `TextChanged` event.

Place your code in a separate method:

```
private void ApplySyntaxHighlite()
{
    string find = "using";
    if (richTextBox1.Text.Contains(find))
    {
        var matchString = Regex.Escape(find);
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(richTextBox1.Text, matchString))
        {
            richTextBox1.Select(match.Index, find.Length);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
            richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.TextLength, 0);
            richTextBox1.SelectionColor = richTextBox1.ForeColor;
        };
    }
}
```

And call it after you set the text in the `RichTextBox`:

```
richTextBox1.Text =
    "using System;\r\nusing System.IO;\r\n\r\nConsole.WriteLine(\"Hello world.\");";

ApplySyntaxHighlite();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! how would i ammend the find string to include 'namespace'  & 'class'  etc

Comment: when I delete a character of a highlighted keyword the font style remains is there a way to fix this?